# How to undo "apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change"?

Tags: apt, raspbian

In an attempt to update a single package, I've inadvertently set myself up to upgrade to 'testing' releases  for firmware instead of the stable ones.  How do I revert my broad 'update' and specify just one repository for --allow-releaseinfo-change?

How I got to where I am while trying to update package 'unifi' from 5.13 to 5.14:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Get:2 https://dl.ubnt.com/unifi/debian stable InRelease [3024 B]
Get:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease [15.0 kB]
Get:4 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages [13.0 MB]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Repository 'https://dl.ubnt.com/unifi/debian stable InRelease' changed its 'Codename' value from 'unifi-5.13' to 'unifi-5.14'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

fine, it won't allow unifi release to change from 5.13 to 5.14 without explicit ok, so:

```
$ sudo apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
Get:3 https://dl.ubnt.com/unifi/debian stable InRelease [3024 B]
Get:4 https://dl.ubnt.com/unifi/debian stable/ubiquiti armhf Packages [713 B]
Fetched 3737 B in 1s (2885 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
N: Repository 'https://dl.ubnt.com/unifi/debian stable InRelease' changed its 'Codename' value from 'unifi-5.13' to 'unifi-5.14'
```

uh oh, I didn't want firmware testing releases from the other repos...

```
$ sudo apt-get --dry-run upgrade unifi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bluez-firmware firmware-atheros firmware-brcm80211 firmware-libertas firmware-misc-nonfree firmware-realtek libgs9 libgs9-common libraspberrypi-bin libraspberrypi-dev libraspberrypi-doc libraspberrypi0
  pi-bluetooth raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel raspi-config rpd-plym-splash unifi
18 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst unifi [5.13.32-13646-1] (5.14.23-13880-1 Ubiquiti Networks, Inc.:stable [all])
Inst bluez-firmware [1.2-4+rpt3] (1.2-4+rpt4 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [all])
Inst firmware-atheros [1:20190114-1+rpt7] (1:20190114-1+rpt8 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [all])
Inst firmware-brcm80211 [1:20190114-1+rpt7] (1:20190114-1+rpt8 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [all])
Inst firmware-libertas [1:20190114-1+rpt7] (1:20190114-1+rpt8 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [all])
Inst firmware-misc-nonfree [1:20190114-1+rpt7] (1:20190114-1+rpt8 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [all])
Inst firmware-realtek [1:20190114-1+rpt7] (1:20190114-1+rpt8 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [all])
Inst libgs9 [9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u3] (9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u4 Raspbian:stable [armhf]) []
Inst libgs9-common [9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u3] (9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u4 Raspbian:stable [all])
Inst libraspberrypi-doc [1.20200811-1] (1.20200819-1 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [armhf]) []
Inst libraspberrypi-dev [1.20200811-1] (1.20200819-1 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [armhf]) []
Inst raspberrypi-kernel [1.20200811-1] (1.20200819-1 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [armhf]) []
Inst libraspberrypi-bin [1.20200811-1] (1.20200819-1 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [armhf]) []
Inst libraspberrypi0 [1.20200811-1] (1.20200819-1 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [armhf]) []
Inst raspberrypi-bootloader [1.20200811-1] (1.20200819-1 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [armhf])
Inst pi-bluetooth [0.1.14] (0.1.15 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [all])
Inst raspi-config [20200727] (20200817 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [all])
Inst rpd-plym-splash [0.23] (0.24 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [armhf])
Conf unifi (5.14.23-13880-1 Ubiquiti Networks, Inc.:stable [all])
Conf bluez-firmware (1.2-4+rpt4 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [all])
Conf firmware-atheros (1:20190114-1+rpt8 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [all])
Conf firmware-brcm80211 (1:20190114-1+rpt8 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [all])
Conf firmware-libertas (1:20190114-1+rpt8 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [all])
Conf firmware-misc-nonfree (1:20190114-1+rpt8 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [all])
Conf firmware-realtek (1:20190114-1+rpt8 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [all])
Conf libgs9 (9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u4 Raspbian:stable [armhf])
Conf libgs9-common (9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u4 Raspbian:stable [all])
Conf libraspberrypi-doc (1.20200819-1 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [armhf])
Conf libraspberrypi-dev (1.20200819-1 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [armhf])
Conf raspberrypi-kernel (1.20200819-1 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [armhf])
Conf libraspberrypi-bin (1.20200819-1 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [armhf])
Conf libraspberrypi0 (1.20200819-1 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [armhf])
Conf raspberrypi-bootloader (1.20200819-1 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [armhf])
Conf pi-bluetooth (0.1.15 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [all])
Conf raspi-config (20200817 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [all])
Conf rpd-plym-splash (0.24 Raspberry Pi Foundation:testing [armhf])
```

and now:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf Packages
     release o=Raspberry Pi Foundation,a=testing,n=buster,l=Raspberry Pi Foundation,c=main,b=armhf
     origin archive.raspberrypi.org
 500 https://www.ui.com/downloads/unifi/debian stable/ubiquiti armhf Packages
     release o=Ubiquiti Networks, Inc.,a=stable,n=unifi-5.14,l=Ubiquiti Networks, Inc.,c=ubiquiti,b=armhf
     origin www.ui.com
 500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/rpi armhf Packages
     release o=Raspbian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Raspbian,c=rpi,b=armhf
     origin raspbian.raspberrypi.org
 500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/non-free armhf Packages
     release o=Raspbian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Raspbian,c=non-free,b=armhf
     origin raspbian.raspberrypi.org
 500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/contrib armhf Packages
     release o=Raspbian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Raspbian,c=contrib,b=armhf
     origin raspbian.raspberrypi.org
 500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages
     release o=Raspbian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Raspbian,c=main,b=armhf
     origin raspbian.raspberrypi.org
Pinned packages:
```

So how do I revert my 'update' so it's not threatening to upgrade to 'testing' releases.
And what should I have done to only pickup the unifi upgrade?